# How to find N most populous cities in each state with TakeLargest and Entity Functions without waiting forever using Caching?

Tags: map, geography, entity, natural-language

I am interested in using Entity Functions such as EntityValue, FilteredEntityClass, EntityFunction, EntityClass, EntityList, and GeoEntities to help me find N most populous cities in each state. I have figured out how to calculate the most populous cities in 1 state, but when I try to scale it to all 50 states it takes a really long time.
I found a similar question about how to find to the twenty most populous cities. I am thinking of applying Map to the function CityData for each state and then applying a function to get the N number of most populous cities for each state to the result of the first mapping.

```
EntityList[
 EntityClass[
  "City", {EntityProperty["City", "AdministrativeDivision"] -> 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", 
      "UnitedStates"}]}]]
```

returns

```
{}
```

and

```
GeoEntities[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Alaska", "UnitedStates"}], "City"]
```

returns

```
GeoEntities::servermessage: Server message: Internal server error.
```

My goal is to first find a way to find the most populous cities in a state and then map that function to all 50 states. My broader interest is in applying Mathematica to geographical computation.

Comment: Could you please include representative code that you have tried out so far?

Comment: Please include your code, not a picture of it, so respondents can paste it in their notebooks. And exactly where were you thinking about using `Map` on all this? You said you could find the most populous city in one state but the code you have shown presents no such output.